# How to access an object instantiated in one activity and running in its own thread, from another activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, runnable

I have a problem getting access to an object that controls audio output and that was created in another activity. Here's the case:

I have a class that implements Runnable so that I can run it in its own thread:

```
public class PulseGenerator implements Runnable {...}
```

In my main activity I instantiate this class, pass the instance to a Thread object and start the thread:

```
noise = new PulseGenerator();
noiseThread = new Thread(noise);
noiseThread.start();
```

I have a few controls in my main activity screen to control internals of 'noise': switch audio on and off, select a waveform, change pulse width and the like. This all works just fine.

Now I want to move a few of these existing and working controls to another screen that I've called 'Settings'. (In order to make room for other additional controls on the main activity screen.) I followed the typical Android approach by creating a new activity for the new Settings screen:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener { ... }
```

This all sounds simple enough. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to get access to the 'noise' object from the new Settings screen/activity/class. When I run the app on the emulator and press a button to switch to the Settings activity, the app crashes ("Unfortunately, xxxxx has stopped.") and in Android Studio's 'Run' view, I get:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException

with a reference to the line number in Settings where I try to access the 'noise' object for the first time. Which makes perfect sense to me, because I have declared, but not initialized the 'noise' object. Because I don't know how, which is the core of this question.

Putting the question more generally, how do I access an object instantiated in one activity and running in its own thread, from another activity?

I am a beginning java and Android programmer and this is my first post, please don't be too brief when answering. Actually I hope it's a 'stupid' beginner's question about multi-activity app programming with an easy answer, so I can move on with my project. I appreciate any help.

PS:
- Standard methods for passing objects between activities don't apply because an object running in its own thread is not serializable. (If I understood correctly.)
- I know of workarounds that use multiple screens per activity (one of them using setVisibility(View.GONE)) and that I could probably get to work. But these solutions lack generality and that's why I don't want to use them.

Comment: There is no way to do this that I know of. What you could try is: a) Save the stuff from the settings activity using 'Shared Preferences' b) as soon as any of the settings have been changed use a 'Broadcast Receiver' on your other activity to update the noise variable

Comment: declare variable noise as static.

Comment: @LineFollower, why won't you declare it as singleton. You can fetch it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities:

- A simple solution would be stopping the thread when an `Activity` is about to finish and restart it in the next Activity. Of course, it depends on what the thread does and whether it is possible at all.
- Wrap the noise thread in a singleton, so you can access the thread from any Activity.
- Create a `Service` and manage the noise thread in there. Maybe you can also reimplement the thread functionality as a Service. From https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html:

  > A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it does not provide a user interface.

  A long-running Service lifecycle is not bound to the lifecycle of an Activity, so even if an Activity finishes, your thread would keep running and would be accessible via the Service that controls it. Mind two things: although a Service doesn't provide UI, it runs on the main UI thread, and a Service might be finished by the operating system, but it can be restarted right after.